# Dynamically change security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri in Spring OAuth2 @EnableResourceServer

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a `Spring Boot` app as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

And i have configured oauth2 properties in `application.properties`.

```
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=http://localhost:9000/user
```

However, I need to change this `URI` depending on the request I send to my `Spring Boot` App.

For example: 
If I receive a request to my `Spring Boot App` to URL `htpp://test.localhost:8000` I would want the `user-info-url` to be `http://test.localhost:9000/user`.

But if I receive a request to `http://localhost:8000` I want the `user-info-url` to be `http://localhost:9000/user`.

My intention is to manage different environments depending on the subdomain.

Is there a way to dynamically change this `URI` in code instead of hardcoding it as a property?

Answer (score 0):

### [Spring Cloud Config](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/)

By leveraging a Spring Cloud Config server, you can externalize your configuration and push updates to application properties.  A simple implementation is backed by a Git repository where you'll store your application.properties file.  You commit your changes and then make a `POST` request the `/refresh` endpoint that will trigger a reload of your configuration.

There are more advanced scenarios as well but hopefully that's enough to get you started.

Here's a simple [Getting Started](https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/) guide.

Comment: But I need a different value 'per request'. If I implemented your suggestion I would be committing a change for every request to my Spring Boot App.

Comment: You're correct, I overlooked that detail in your question.  Can you provide some clarity on what the different requests would be and the overall logic behind this architecture?  Thanks!

Comment: I added that clarification in the Question. Thanks!